# Creating continuous line graph in ggplot with NA values and adding secondary y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, yaxis

I would like to create a continuous time-series line graph. However, I have `NA` values in my data so the typical output is discontinuous. I tried using the `na.omit` argument but an error appears

> Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard
> unambiguous format"

Here is my script:

```
test <- read.csv(
  file=paste0("testdata.csv"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

test$Date <- as.Date(test$Date)

ggplot(na.omit(test), aes(x=Date, y=A))+
  geom_line(na.rm=TRUE)+
  xlab("") + ylab("A")+
  (scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("1 month"),labels=date_format("%b")))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(28, 31))+
  geom_point(shape=1)+
  theme_bw()
```

Aside from that, I would also like to create a second y-axis in the same plot. I used `sec.axis` argument. The data for this axis also has `NA` values. However, since the first part of the script is having problems, I can not confirm if my code works. Here is the additional code:

```
  geom_line(aes(y = B/20, colour ="B")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*20, bquote(B)))+
    geom_point(shape=0)
```

Here is a portion of my data

| Date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-23 | 28.2 | NA |
| 2020-09-30 | NA | 0.192 |
| 2020-10-01 | 28.4 | NA |
| 2020-10-07 | 28.6 | NA |
| 2020-10-14 | 28.8 | NA |
| 2020-10-21 | 28 | NA |
| 2020-10-28 | NA | 0.136 |
| 2020-11-01 | 28.5 | NA |
| 2020-11-04 | 27.6 | NA |
| 2020-11-11 | 27.9 | NA |
| 2020-11-18 | 27.9 | NA |
| 2020-11-25 | NA | 0.184 |
| 2020-12-01 | 28.1 | NA |
| 2020-12-02 | 28.4 | NA |
| 2020-12-09 | 29 | NA |

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is what you want that portion of data's `B` have a lot of `NA`'s.

comment: if `na.omit` to portion of data, nothing left so I cannot proceed with `na.omit`.

```
test2 <- test %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))

test3 <- test2 %>%
  select(Date, A) %>%
  na.omit 

test3 %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=A))+
  geom_line(na.rm=TRUE)+
  xlab("") + ylab("A")+
  (scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("1 month"),labels=date_format("%b")))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(28, 31))+
  geom_point(shape=1)+
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line(data = test2, aes(x = Date,y = B/20, colour ="B")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*20, bquote(B)))+
  geom_point(shape=0,data = test2,aes(y = B* 20, colour ="B"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Park! Yes the data is just a portion of a larger data set so there are a lot of NA. Would you know how I can connect the data points so they will not appear as just points/discontinuous?

Comment: @okscientist I'm afraid that you cannot make every points continuous.  I edit my code to make `A` continuous